# Suggested/recommended use for {% block extraBody %}

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Did not find an example or recommended use of {% block extraBody %}

Your thought please.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `extraBody` nunjucks block in `outerLayoutBase` is to allow you to add code that you wish to place immediately before the closing `</body>` tag without being forced to override `outerLayoutBase` completely. You might, for instance, want to place third-party `script` tags here to avoid blocking rendering of the page while they load and run, if the script in question is not a good candidate for the `async` attribute.

Our goal with `outerLayoutBase` is to ensure that we insert Apostrophe's markup as part of a standardized base template that is flexible enough that people don't feel forced to override it and then have difficulty with markup we need to insert for Apostrophe later because they do not have the necessary template code in their stale copy of `outerLayoutBase`. Project level code should, if needed, start with an override of `outerLayout` that extends `outerLayoutBase` and just overrides a few blocks rather than reinventing the wheel. You'll note that the "stock" version of `outerLayout` is intentionally set up this way — it just extends `outerLayoutBase` and does nothing else. Your version can extend `outerLayoutBase` and override some blocks.

We encourage our own in-house developers to follow this rule, and to add new blocks to `outerLayoutBase` if they would otherwise be forced to override it, as a way of ensuring that other developers find the needed flexibility is there for them as well.